# Image Not Uploading To PHP Server in React Native

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data, multipart

I am trying To upload Image to PHP server from react native. But I Am not able to Upload Image. I try all stuff. I am not getting any error , warning. Not any single error. still I am not able to upload Image to Server . WHY?????

here is my code

```
onst App = () => {

  const [singleFile, setSingleFile] = useState(null);

  const uploadImage = async () => {

    if (singleFile != null) {

       const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("lead_tag_number", "NAS00001");
      formData.append("upload_pan_card_file", singleFile.singleFile.replace('file:/','file://'))
    
       console.log(formData._parts[1][1])
      
      fetch('https://xyz.tech/Android_API_CI/up_data',
        {
          method: 'post',
            // body: JSON.stringify([{formData}]),
            body : formData._parts[1][1],
          headers: {
            
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
            
          },
          
        }
      )

  .then(response => response.text())

  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  
  };
}

  const selectFile = async () => {
      let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        // base64: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      });

        setSingleFile({ singleFile : pickerResult.uri});
        console.log(singleFile.singleFile.replace('file:/','file://'))
   
  };
```

I am getting response from server like this

```
here------------1<pre>files dataArray
(
// I want My Image Here //
)
here you are
```

please help

Comment: have you tried to pass it to request body just as formData ```body: formData```?

Comment: yes but same happens

Comment: I want to send key for that Image object . How do I send That

Comment: what does your server expect to receive?

Comment: Image  A Image A imag